ReplayKit, ZoomSDK for iOS, EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception
Xcode 15.4
iOS 17.5
I'm trying to use ZoomVideoSDK in my iOS app to start a broadcast (Share the entire screen), I followed their documentation and created the app group and the extension target correctly.
When i start my broadcast using the extension, after 2-3 seconds I get this exception:
Thread 3: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x78)
in this function:
override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
        // Pass sample buffer into SDK.
        print("Processing sample buffer: \(sampleBufferType)")
        screenShareService?.processSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer, with: sampleBufferType)
    }

screenShareService?.processSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer, with: sampleBufferType) is causing this crash.
I debugged and made sure that screenShareService is initialized.
I double checked the main target and extension target group definitions.
I tried to add the TeamID to the app group definition.
I attached the debugger, and I can always see this log right before the crash happens:
*** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1,100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x5627, name = '<private>' See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
I'm not sure if it's related to the issue or just a warning.
